# Extract column values from pubsub output using apache beam in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to extract data from PubSub subscription and finally, once the data is extracted I want to do some transformation. Currently, it's in bytes format. I have tried multiple ways to extract the data in JSON format using custom schema it fails with an error

```
raise TypeError(TypeError: Parameter to an Iterable hint must be a non-sequence, a type, or a TypeConstraint. <class 'dict'> is an instance of type.
```

**readPubSub.py**

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import json
import typing

class MySchema(typing.NamedTuple):
    user_id:str
    event_ts:str    
    create_ts:str   
    event_id:str    
    ifa:str
    ifv:str
    country:str
    chip_balance:str    
    game:str    
    user_group:str
    user_condition:str  
    device_type:str 
    device_model:str    
    user_name:str   
    fb_connect:bool 
    is_active_event:bool    
    event_payload:str

TOPIC_PATH = "projects/nectar-259905/topics/events"

def pubsub_to_dict(pubsub_message: str) -> dict:
    dicts_as_string = pubsub_message.replace(' ','').split('\n\n')
    for dict_as_string in dicts_as_string:
        yield eval(dict_as_string)

def run(pubsub_topic):
    options = PipelineOptions(
        streaming=True
    )
    runner = 'DirectRunner'

    print("I reached before pipeline")

    with beam.Pipeline(runner, options=options) as pipeline:
        message=(
                        pipeline
        | "Read from Pub/Sub topic" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription='projects/triple-nectar-259905/subscriptions/bq_subscribe')#.with_output_types(bytes)
        | 'UTF-8 bytes to string' >> beam.Map(lambda msg: msg.decode('utf-8'))
        | 'Split Into Dicts' >> beam.Map(pubsub_to_dict)
        | 'Map to MySchema' >> beam.Map(lambda msg: MySchema(**msg)).with_output_types(MySchema)
        | "Writing to console" >> beam.Map(print))
        
    print("I reached after pipeline")
    result = message.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


run(TOPIC_PATH)
```

If I use it directly below

```
message=(
    pipeline
    | "Read from Pub/Sub topic" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription='projects/triple-nectar-259905/subscriptions/bq_subscribe')#.with_output_types(bytes)
    | 'UTF-8 bytes to string' >> beam.Map(lambda msg: msg.decode('utf-8'))
    | "Writing to console" >> beam.Map(print))
```

I get output as

```
    {
        'user_id': '102105290400258488',
        'event_ts': '2021-05-29 20:42:52.283 UTC',
        'event_id': 'Game_Request_Declined',
        'ifa': '6090a6c7-4422-49b5-8757-ccfdbad',
        'ifv': '3fc6eb8b4d0cf096c47e2252f41',
        'country': 'US',
        'chip_balance': '9140',
        'game': 'gru',
        'user_group': '[1, 36, 529702]',
        'user_condition': '[1, 36]',
        'device_type': 'phone',
        'device_model': 'TCL 5007Z',
        'user_name': 'Minnie',
        'fb_connect': True,
        'event_payload': '{"competition_type":"normal","game_started_from":"result_flow_rematch","variant":"target"}',
        'is_active_event': True
    }

{
    'user_id': '102105290400258488',
    'event_ts': '2021-05-29 20:54:38.297 UTC',
    'event_id': 'Decline_Game_Request',
    'ifa': '6090a6c7-4422-49b5-8757-ccfdbad',
    'ifv': '3fc6eb8b4d0cf096c47e2252f41',
    'country': 'US',
    'chip_balance': '9905',
    'game': 'gru',
    'user_group': '[1, 36, 529702]',
    'user_condition': '[1, 36]',
    'device_type': 'phone',
    'device_model': 'TCL 5007Z',
    'user_name': 'Minnie',
    'fb_connect': True,
    'event_payload': '{"competition_type":"normal","game_started_from":"result_flow_rematch","variant":"target"}',
    'is_active_event': True
}
```

Please let me know if I m doing something wrong while parsing the data to JSON. Also, I am looking for examples to do data masking and run some SQL within Apache Beam

Comment: Is the example output you are showing one single PubSub message or are those two separate events?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by `ast.literal_eval` which fails to evaluate the value of the field `event_payload` (which is not in a correct json format).

You need to split the pubsub message into individual dicts, using

```
def pubsub_to_dict(pubsub_message: str) -> dict:
   # it could be that you need to adjust the code a little bit, in case the actual pubsub return differs from the way I ingested your example data
   # the idea: first remove all whitespaces, then split at the line break between the dicts
   dicts_as_string = pubsub_message.replace(' ','').split('\n\n')
   for dict_as_string in dicts_as_string:
       return eval(dict_as_string)
```

Afterwards, you can just fill your NamedTuple with a simple `beam.Map` like this

```
with beam.Pipeline(runner, options=options) as pipeline:
        message=(
            pipeline
            | "Read from Pub/Sub topic" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription='projects/nectar-259905/subscriptions/bq_subscribe')#.with_output_types(bytes)
            | 'UTF-8 bytes to string' >> beam.Map(lambda msg: msg.decode('utf-8'))
            | 'Split Into Dicts' >> beam.Map(pubsub_to_dict)
            | 'Map to MySchema' >> beam.Map(lambda msg: MySchema(**msg)).with_output_types(MySchema)
```

`MySchema(**msg)` works only, if the NamedTuple is identical to the structure of `msg`. Should they differ, you need to manually fill the schema, e.g.

```
MySchema(
 field_1 = msg['key_1'],
 field_2 = msg['key_2']
)
```

Comment: pls check the question, I have updated the post. These are not two events. I wanted to show if it's printing the output correctly.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I m facing a different error-raise TypeError( TypeError: Parameter to an Iterable hint must be a non-sequence, a type, or a TypeConstraint. <class 'dict'> is an instance of type

Comment: Its hard to debug from remote, but I think you need to use `return` instead of `yield` in the `pubsub_to_dict` I've written above